# whats wrongin the query

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT emplname, length(emplname) AS m
    FROM employeesinfo
) as k
where m = (select max(m) from k);
```

what is wrong with this code it is showing table doesn't exist error *1146*

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I would rephrase your syntax as:

```
SELECT emplname, LENGTH(emplname) AS name_length
FROM employeesinfo
WHERE LENGTH(emplname) = (SELECT MAX(LENGTH(emplname)) FROM employeesinfo);
```

Another general way of doing this would be to use the `RANK` analytic function:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT emplname, LENGTH(emplname) AS name_length,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LENGTH(emplname) DESC) rnk
    FROM employeesinfo
)

SELECT emplname, name_length
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

If you only expect one record with the maximum length, then on MySQL we can use `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT emplname, LENGTH(emplname) AS name_length
FROM employeesinfo
ORDER BY LENGTH(emplname) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: sELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT emplname, length(emplname) AS m
    FROM employeesinfo
) as k
where m = 6 but it is executing why...?? u told correct i didnt have knowledge in cte

Answer (score 0):

The table `k` doesn't not refer to the derived table in this query:

```
SELECT k.*
FROM ( SELECT emplname, length(emplname) as m FROM employeesinfo
     ) k 
WHERE m = (SELECT max(m) FROM k);
```

You may be confusing subqueries and CTEs.  If you define this as a CTE, then it will work:

```
WITH k as (
      SELECT emplname, length(emplname) as m
      FROM employeesinfo
     )
SELECT k.*
FROM k
WHERE m = (SELECT MAX(m) FROM k);
```

I should note that there might be better ways to handle this.  For instance, if there is only one maximum expected, then you could use:

```
select k.*
from k
order by length(emplname) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: sELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT emplname, length(emplname) AS m
    FROM employeesinfo
) as k
where m = 6 but it is executing why...?? u told correct i didnt have knowledge in cte